# Why I am getting varied results when using sizeof for same char array?

Tags: c++, c++14

In main class I print sizeof(person->name) and then I do sizeof(name)  which are same
as I pass same char array to Person constructor.
But why I get varied results in both cases
in first case sizeof returns 32
whereas in second case sizeof return 6
[This is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cJgf.jpg)

This is the code :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.h"

int main()
{

    char name[] = {'H','o','b','b','i','t'};
    Person *person = new Person(name , 203);

    std::cout << "p->Name size - " << sizeof(person->name) << " char array size   " << sizeof(name) << std::endl;

    delete person;

    return 0;

}
```

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>

Person::Person(){};

Person::Person(char name[],int age)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->age = age;
}

Person::~Person()
{
    std::cout << "\n Destructor called" << std::endl;
}

void Person::sayHello()
{
    std::cout << "\n Hello " << this->name << " " << this->age << std::endl ;   
}
```

Comment: What type is person->name?

Comment: You left out the type of `Person::name`, but I'm guessing that it's `std::string`, and you would find hints by comparing your numbers to `sizeof(std::string)`and `sizeof(char[6])`.

Comment: it is of string type

Comment: does std::string consume more space than char of same length

Comment: Note that since you left out the zero terminator in `name`, making a `std::string` from it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user7695301 All instances of the same type have the same size.

Comment: It adds that automatically , on my observation std::string consumes 5 times more bytes than char array

Comment: There is no relationship between the `sizeof` a `string` and the length of the `string` in characters. `sizeof` only provides the size in bytes of a type. At it's most basic, `string` is a pointer to a buffer containing the characters and a count of the number of characters, for a size of, probably 8 to 16 byes no matter how many characters the `string` owns and references. Use `string::size` or `string::length` instead.

Comment: Try this: `char name1[] = {'H','o','b','b','i','t'}, name2[] = "Hobbit"; std::cout << "size 1: " << sizeof name1 << " size 2: " << sizeof name2 << '\n';`. Spoiler alert: Output: `size 1: 6 size 2: 7`. The latter is a valid initialization for `std::string` (without explicitly giving size) because it's zero-terminated the former not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof` in a `std::string` does not measure the complete amount of memory the string occupies. It measures how large the `std::string` object is.

The `sizeof` on a `std::string` is a constant value that is independent on the length of the string that is stored in it.

A `std::string` does have an overhead compared to a `char name[]` due to meta information and small string optimizations, and that overhead is (depending on the implementation) at a maximum of around 20 bytes.

For a range of 0 - ~20 chars a `std::string` will always occupy ~20 bytes memory. For more than ~20 chars the `std::string` will occupy ~20 + number of char bytes.

So yes for a really small number of chars it can be 5 times more bytes. But for a normal use case, that overhead can be ignored.